# I need to find the equation of a line tangent to the function $f(x)= x^3+2$ and parallel to the line $3x-y-4=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the equation of a line tangent to the function $f(x)= x^3+2$ and parallel to the line $3x-y-4=0$. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

So the gradient of $$y=3x-4$$ is $3$

Now $$\dfrac{d f(x)}{dx}=3x^2$$ which needs to be $1$

$\implies x_0=\pm1, y_0=x_0^3+2$

$$3=\dfrac{y-(x_0^3+2)}{x-x_0}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints. 1) The equation of the tangent to $f$ at $x_0$ is given by
$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0).$$

2) Two lines $y=m_1 x+q_1$ and $y=m_2 x+q_2$ are parallel iff $m_1=m_2$.

3) By 1) and 2) you have to solve $3x_0^2=f'(x_0)=3$.

How many tangents have the required property?

P.S. Following the above hints, we have that there are two tangents:

i) $y=3x$ at $x_0=1$, and ii) $y=3x+4$ at $x_0=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of line is $y=ax+b$. It is parallel to $y=3x-4$, thus $a=3$.

Also it is tangent to $y=x^3+2$, thus $3x^2=3$ and $x=\pm1$. So we intersect the line with the curve at the given points: $$3(1)+b=(1)^3+2 \Rightarrow b=0$$ and $$3(-1)+b=(-1)^3+2 \Rightarrow b=4$$

[image]